# why are model's hash field keys not saved as symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm using mongoid in my project and have a model which has a hash field:

```
field :settings, type: Hash
```

I defined a `after_create` callback to set some settings after model creation:

```
after_create :set_settings
def set_settings
settings[:test] = true
save!
end
```

but now i see that the hash is saved with string keys and not with symbol keys:

```
 {"test"=>true}
```

and then I tried `symbolize_keys` like this:

```
settings[:test] = true
settings.symbolize_keys!
save!
```

but it didn't work.

the point is that if we do those procedures in the console manually, the hash is saved with symbol keys!

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses the class [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) to allow keys of a Hash to be accessed with either strings or symbols, regarless of the underlying implementation. I suspect that somewhere behind the scenes, your hash is getting converted to one of these objects.

As for why the keys are saved as strings, I suspect is has to do with the fact that [symbols are not garbage collected](http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/memory-and-ruby-symbols/), and that fact can be exploited to allow for DOS attacks if you're not careful.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, Ruby Hash maps and serializes to a BSON document (or embedded document)
with (e_name) keys that are CStrings. Reference:

http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

So keys are stringified on serialization, collapsing string keys and symbol keys together and loosing the distinction.
On deserialization back into Ruby hashes, the current drivers map to string keys.
In the MongoDB, Inc. Ruby driver (mongo gem, github mongo-ruby-driver) version 1.8,
we tried to address this by defining our own HashWithIndifferentAccess ala Rails,
but with symbols internally rather than strings.
However we ran into complications with the Java extension for JRuby and had to revert the feature.  Reference:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-434

In the 2.0 version, we're planning to use the new bson-ruby https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby implementation
which is predominantly Ruby with minimal C and Java extensions.
We should be able to revisit the implementation.

There are some performance considerations.
At present Symbol#to_s is more expensive than expected as a new String is generated.
Seems like a nice Ruby core language optimization would be to memoize the string.
So serializing symbol keys is actually more expensive than serializing string keys.

Please feel free to open a new Ruby ticket and request "Queries should return a Hash w/ Indifferent Access."
It will help us to prioritize.